# Fourier series at discontinuity point

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-series

I have a function with period $T = 2\pi$ defined as

$f(x) = x + 3 \quad\textrm{if}\quad 0\leq x<2\pi$

I calculated the Fourier series at points $x\neq 0 + kT$

$f(x)=\pi+3+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}-\frac{2}{n}sin(nx)$

Now they ask me to find the Fourier series at points $x=0 + kT$

What I did is I know the Fourier series converges to $\frac{1}{2}[f(x<0+kT)+f(x>0+kT)]$, which in this case is $\pi + 3$ so is it correct to say that the Fourier series at the points of discontinuity is $f(x) = \pi+3$?

Comment: what mean the expression $f(x<0+kT)$?

Comment: x is less than the point of discontinuity

Comment: You are correct except that you are formulating the answer confusingly as the Fourier series is $g(x)=\pi+3+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}-\frac{2}{n}sin(nx)$ and indeed $g(x)=f(x)=x+3, x \ne 2k\pi$ while $g(2k\pi)=\pi+3$ either by quoted result or directly as the series is just zero

Comment: yes, thank you! that's what was confusing me @Conrad